# Error when installing ggplot2, need c compiler

Tags: r, macos, gcc, ggplot2, stringi

I'm trying to install `ggplot2` on a collaborator's Mac computer. I get this error:

```
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘stringi’
```

It looks like I need to install a C compiler. After searching around, the only thing I see mentioned is `gcc`. To install this, I need to install XCode from the App store. When I try to install XCode, I get a message saying that Mac OS 10.10 or higher is required. His machine is 10.7.5, so it won't intstall.

Is there any way that I can install `gcc`?

Comment: Take a look here: [Github](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer)

Comment: You should be able to obtain an older version of XCode from the [Developer Center](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&baseURL=https://developer.apple.com/&path=%2F%2Fdownloads%2F&rv=1).

Comment: @Shelltux Thanks. I was able to install `gcc` from that link.